# Blank screen on laptop after replacement

Tags: windows-7, laptop, lcd

I have an Acer Aspire 5332 laptop, running Windows 7 home premium 32bit. My screen broke, but the particular screen (LED) are no longer made so I bought a CCFL one with a new converter which has proven to be compatible according to the supplier.

When I first booted the screen went blank just after the Windows logo was displayed. I suspected a driver issue, so booted in safe mode without any problems, disabled the display adapter (Intel 4 series express family) and it booted up fine. So I guess the screen is not compatible with the display adapter.

The driver version is 8.15.10.1892. I tried updating from the Intel site, but it saying it cannot (something to do with manufacturer specific). The supplier is not willing to take it back, so I'm down £60 (UK).

I can use it with the adapter disabled, but the quality is bad and I cannnot play video, etc. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The supplier must take it back. You bought a lemon.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the screen, as i said, it works with the graphics adapter disabled. It probably a software issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had the same problem on a customer's Acer laptop with a 15.6 screen. I assume you meant that the old screen was CCFL and you replaced it with a LED one as that is what I've just done.

It seems the fault is caused by insufficient power being sent to the part of the screen's integrated circuit board that switches the LEDs on. All you need to do is go into control panel and adjust the power settings to maximum brightness for both "plugged in" and "on battery" and that ought to do the trick!

You can't do this in safe mode so unless you disable the graphics driver first you'll be using a torch held close to the screen but afterwards you can enable it again and all should be working.

Where did you get your screen from? Just so I don't use them as a supplier…

Answer (score 0):

Plug it in to an external monitor and set your power/brightness settings and make sure the brightness is set to 100%.  For what ever reason, there's no brightness adjust on some of the conversions, so it's either 100% or nothing.